# Getting time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Tags: python, csv, python-datetime

I'm having a datetime error but only for some rows. Here's my code:

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime

def import_data_files():
  r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anyoneai/notebooks/main/customers_and_orders/data/orders.csv')
  with open('./sample_data/orders.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
  
import_data_files()

path = './sample_data/orders.csv'
row_cnt = 0
orders_placed = 0
orders_date = []

with open(path, 'r') as fl:
  csv = csv.reader(fl, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  next(csv)
  for CustomerID, OrderID, Date, OrderTotal, ProductName, Price in csv:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    if date.year == 2021:
      if date.month == 10:
        #print(Date)
        #print(date)
        orders_placed+=1
        row_cnt+=1
        if row_cnt > 234:
        #if row_cnt > 232:
          break


print(orders_placed)
```

if I run until row 232 everything works, but if I run more than that I get an error. Parsing only the strings without timedata conversion I can get the result, but I don't know if that's ok or maybe I'm missing something. Here's the string code:

```
import requests
import csv

def import_data_files():
  r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anyoneai/notebooks/main/customers_and_orders/data/orders.csv')
  with open('./sample_data/orders.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
  
import_data_files()

path = './sample_data/orders.csv'
orders_placed = 0

with open(path, 'r') as fl:
  csv = csv.reader(fl, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  next(csv)
  for CustomerID, OrderID, Date, OrderTotal, ProductName, Price in csv:
    date = Date.split(" ")
    date = Date.split("-")
    if date[0] == '2021':
      if date[1] == '10':
        orders_placed+=1

print(orders_placed)
```

Comment: Sounds like your file ends with one or more empty lines.

Comment: is the data well formated on the row that raises the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the rows do not contain a date field. In these cases `Date` is empty and as such your `.strptime()` call will fail. I suggest you skip over these rows, for example:

```py
import requests
import csv
import datetime

def import_data_files():
    r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anyoneai/notebooks/main/customers_and_orders/data/orders.csv')
  
    with open('orders.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
  
import_data_files()

path = 'orders.csv'
orders_placed = 0
orders_date = []

with open(path, 'r') as fl:
    csv = csv.reader(fl, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(csv)
  
    for row_number, (CustomerID, OrderID, Date, OrderTotal, ProductName, Price) in enumerate(csv):
        if Date:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

            if date.year == 2021 and date.month == 10:
                orders_placed += 1

print(orders_placed)
```

This would display: `437`

---

Normally a row looks like:

```
1900610,7692429,2020-01-12 13:52:40.677,200.0000,0981,200.0000
```

But the failing rows without a date look like:

```
5014,5365,,120.0000,211,60.0000
```

Comment: Yes that's right those rows where missing, but only the date, thanks for the comment!